# Ios how can I verify that the phone number entered is actually the users phone number?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, sms-gateway

I have seen a couple different apps (Snapchat, whatsapp, etc.) ask users to input their phone number.  A text message is then sent to the user with a code to verify that the number is actually their number. Then they are able to see which of the users address book contacts also have the app.

I understand how all of this works except how they are sending the text messages to the user.  Are they running their own SMS Gateway like Kannel, using an SMS gateway provider like twilio, or am I completely missing another option?

Seems like using a gateway provider even at 1 cent a message would add up very quickly especially when you are really only trying to protect the app from the few users that purposely put in the wrong phone number.

Comment: Any appropriate SMS gateway/provider should work. There is no "one right" answer. Anyway, apps are supposed to *make* money - so hopefully you have the cashflow stuff planned.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the apps use sms gateway services, yes sms is costly, there is another way to verify the user number by missed call trick.
http://dial2verify.com/

Comment: what is this missed call trick?? How to implement and what is the success rate?

Comment: miss call trick is ask the user to input his number then ask him to give a miss call to your number (provided by the dial2verify or some other service) from his mobile and on receiving the miss call, dail2verify will give your application a callback with details to validate the mobile number, there are available solutions on the market, one such solution is http://dial2verify.com/ you will need to integrate with the dail2verify api, http://kb.dial2verify.in/ not sure about the success rate, we are also trying it out... looks promising so far

Comment: Looks great and seems less economy for small apps.

Comment: @Devashish how to integrate this in iOS?

Comment: @AzharBandri nothing specific to iOS, dial2verify provides REST API which your application need to call, for more details, visit https://www.kb.dial2verify.in/questions/16/Dial2Verify+-+API+Version+2+-+Introduction