# Mobile Number Verification with Missed Call in iOS

Tags: ios

I don't know this question is a good question or dumb question, but I research on SO from last 3 days, only this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308502/ios-how-can-i-verify-that-the-phone-number-entered-is-actually-the-users-phone-n) I am able to see. And in this link I am not getting any solution for my Issue.

My question is How to verify my mobile number with a missed call. I got from some answer, have to use "**Dial2Verify**" API. But no one can said "*How to use that API*" in iOS mobile application through coding. I follow **Dial2Verify** site for more information, but its only for PHP developer.

My requirement is: I have a call button on my app screen, when I pressed that button, that method will call to **Dial2Verify** API, And give a missed call to **Dial2Verify** API and after register Dial2Verify will send that API key/ Mobile number to my App Server, Then App server will check the mobile number is registered or not, if register then it directly go to Home page off App otherwise stay on that Login page.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use of mOTP API. (MOTP.in )
Again a service by dial2verify, but it is more suitable for app integration as it supports 200+ countries.

A clever alternative to SMS otp.

At the core it's a 2 step process.
1 sending mOTP : you would be required to call a remote URL from app ( which would send missed call otp to end user )

Step 2: you are required to call another URL from app to cross check otp entered by user.

There is a flow demo available on mOTP website.

Do share the code you build so others can be benefited.

Comment: Ok dude. I have to check with mOTP :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a service like https://checkmobi.com/ . Basically they have available 4 validations methods: SMS, IVR, Missed call (the one you need) and another one called CLI.

You can check how each method is working here: https://checkmobi.com/documentation.html#/overview

Also they have available a iOS and Android SDK for mobiles and quite good pricing model for startups.